# is there any way to replace only last segment of url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am having 5000 records and i display 100 records on each page and for another 100 records i am using two links (next , previous).
for NEXT anchor tag i am giving controller path like - 
www.website.com/controller/ function/range_of_records.

At first time when i click on NEXT link another 100 records are display properly but when i click  second time on NEXT link url become like -

www.website.com/controller/function/range / controller / function /range .

So it gives error .
I want only change the 3 segment of url like only change the range segment.

Please help me.

Comment: [Share the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: use codeingniter pagination